# LinQ into variable without losing reference

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've been looking for this, but I can't find an answer. The only thing I get is linq projections, but nothing on this.

I have a function receiving a entity framework table parameter lets say "customer", like this:

```
public partial class customer
{
    public customer()
    {
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public bool activo { get; set; }

}
```

........

```
public virtual customer Load(customer paramEntity)
{
      using (BillingDbContext bd = new BillingDbContext())
      {
          paramEntity = (from s in bd.customer
                    select s).First();
      }

      return paramEntity;
}
```

NOTE: the First() is only for the example, I'm actually using a function with a predicate parameter to filter (where) the results

What I want is, instead of receiving a new object from the linq, use the linq to populate my parameter (paramEntity), so I won't lose my parameter reference.

Is this possible? without copying each property from one variable to another?

Why I want this? Because when I call the function, I use an inherited class from customer, and I want later to override the Load function. like this:

```
public class customerX : customer
{    
    public float saldo {get; set;}

}
```

........

```
public override customer Load(customer paramEntity)
{
        customerX e = (customerX)base.Load(paramEntity);
        e.saldo = SomeFunctionLoadSaldo(e.id);

        return e;
}
```

........

```
customerX c = (customerX)Load(new customerX());
```

NOTE: if I won't pass the inherited class (customerX) from the beginning, then in the "base.Load" throw me an error, because it cant cast from customer to customerX. That's why I need to keep my variable reference.

Comment: create a CustomerX in the Query? Aka select new CustomerX {} instead of a simple select s.

Comment: @Ralf That still won't populate the passed in instance, but rather create a new one.

Comment: the only way I see to do it is to copy every property from one object to the adder.

Comment: @Servy - I was presenting an alternative because IMHO what he wants isn't really possible.

Comment: I think you are looking for a way to copy the data from one object to another, am I correct?

Comment: @Ralf Sure it's possible.  Just copy over each property.  It's tedious, but certainly *possible*.

Comment: yeah, thats the only solution i found, but is the one i dont want :)

Comment: @g.Raam yes, but i want linq populate it, if its possible inside the sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`AutoMapper`](http://automapper.org/) to move the properties from one object to another. E.g.

```
public virtual customer Load(customer paramEntity)
{
    using (BillingDbContext bd = new BillingDbContext())
    {
        var dbEntity = (from s in bd.customer
                    select s).First();
        Mapper.Map(dbEntity, paramEntity);
    }

    return paramEntity;
}
```

Comment: Seconded, AutoMapper feels like cheating.

Comment: so its not possible to populate the variable from linq?

Comment: @jrivam It shouldn't, even if it would be.  LINQ is for *querying*.  It's for fetching data.  LINQ queries shouldn't be causing side effects, such as changing the data in some existing object instance.  That said, it's not even *possible* through an EF query; it would need to be linq to objects code for the LINQ code to even have access to the variable.

Answer (score -1):

Considering that Customer is a *class*, so a *reference type* by coding like you wrote:

```
(from s in bd.customer select s).First();
```

you actually return a the same reference available in collection, like a `LINQ` query. In your case refering to the database you need a method that projects data from the object constructed form database to the object you already have.

Comment: .First() can be null - Always check for null or Linq will throw an exemption

Comment: @PhilVallone good point, thank you, i will. the First() is only for the example, im actually using a function with a predicate parameter to filter the results.